# Cannot start Arduino IDE after playing with several versions of it

Tags: arduino-ide, linux

On my Linux Mint 17 Quiana I have manually downloaded and ran several versions of the arduino IDE (1.05 which is in the repo, 1.6.x for some time, now 1.8.3). Things worked like a charm.

Now I am trying to get the IDE 1.8.5 going, but I cannot get the IDE started. Started means: I download, extract the files to a directory and run the install.sh command such that the desktop icon gets created. This finishe with a success message. Now I am clicking on the desktop icon, but nothing happens.

Need to say that the IDE 1.05 which comes as a package with Qiana works just fine. I have run the install.sh of both to and fro, but only the 1.05 will start properly. I checked on the desktop link, the execution rights, user, group etc. They are all looking fine for 1.8.5 but it wont start.

I tried to start the 1.85 arduino IDE from the command line - hoping to get some clue from error messages:

```
java -DAPP_DIR=/opt/arduino-1.8.5/ Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel processing.app.Base
```

--> running this it tells me, that the main class cannot be found.

Any hints where I am going wrong? Are there any config files to be cleared up, paths to be set ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not *need* to install Arduino at all. In fact I have never had it work right due to things not being found.

All you need to do is, from a terminal, run the `arduino` command in the extracted directory:

```
fred@computer:~/arduino-1.8.5 $ ./arduino
```

Any errors that then throws will be a clue as to why it doesn't want to work.

Comment: Hi there
thanks for replying. I found the issue based on the idea to call arduino from the command line as proposed by you. Stupid me had downloaded the 64bit version but am still running on a 32bit kernel. I now got the 32 bit IDE and it works like a charm.
The problem was so weird - it had to be something stupid :-/

Best
Al

Answer (score 0):

1.05 is the latest available packaged version (and is quite dated).

You can download and (optionally) install the new version. See [Installing Arduino IDE on Linux](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/44591/installing-arduino-ide-on-linux)

Either remove (or ignore) the old version. Apart from the additional support the new version supplies, the directories differ - you can either change to the new (recommended) or change the settings.

There is no NEED to "install" the new version. The supplied script DOES NOT `install` in the traditional sense, it merely installs GUI links to the download.